# What deployment framework to use?

Tags: python, linux, windows, deployment

We are trying to figure out what deployment method/framework to use with a python application, it has a basic wsgi server to make some REST resources available and a set of static web pages with the interface that are served through Apache.

**The situation is as follows:**

My team works in isolated parts of the program and sometimes together in specific modules, we have different testing servers and one master server, we all work locally, sync the code using git, and then run a bash script that copies the files from the windows machines to the indicated Linux server(using SSH) and then restarts the app. After thinking about it this doesn't seem to be the right way to do it, the script overwrites all the files in the server with the local files every time.

We want to be able to work in the same server without the worry of overwriting other people's code and we need to deploy to different servers to avoid restarting the service while others work with it and in the near future we need to deploy to the master or several clones of the master server when the application reaches a more mature state.

We found several options: capistrano, kwate, chef or fortress, even fleet but we wanted to have opinions from people that has used them to be sure it is what we need.

**So this are the main questions:**

1. Are these the kind of programs we should be looking at to achieve a
   safe concurrent deployment process?
2. Which one have you used/recommend and why? do you think it would
   help in our actual situation?

Comment: Seems a question for here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rantanplan: Programmers.SE does not accept shopping questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought it fell under the `development methodologies` of Programmers.SE. But now I read the FAQ where it says not to post questions about `tools`. So I guess that is what you're referring to. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

We are using fabric and having no problems with it. Simple to write/support/understand. Good documentation and a lot of articles from 'googling'.

http://docs.fabfile.org/

P.S. We are also using git.